# Low level alternative to bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add()? Blender 2.8

Tags: python, uv

I was looking through the blender 2.8 bees but I can't find anything, I've seen on some forums using the bmesh module, but I'm not sure it's the right way.

I could use the operator but I already know that on large scenes inserting the ops in a "for" loop would become very slow.

bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add()

Comment: You just want to add a UV map, not generating it in a particular way?

Comment: This is a good question, I noticed that by default it spreads the map on every single polygon, I would like to understand how to do this, it would also be good to understand how to simulate a "Smart uv" I didn't find much about it

Comment: I don't think smart uv corresponds to API which is not bpy.ops (to verify). But just for texture_add, you can obj.data.uv_layers.new(name="UvMap")

Comment: @lemon This is exactly what I was looking for, you should enter it as an answer, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *low-level* alternative to [`bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add) is [`obj.data.uv_layers.new(name="UvMap")`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UVLoopLayers.html#bpy.types.UVLoopLayers.new). This way you don't need to set the operator context.

Though, it will not allow complex unwrapping such as [Smart UV Project](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.uv.html#bpy.ops.uv.smart_project).

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer above further, here is how you can add a new uv_layer to all meshes in the scene and select it as the active uvmap.

```
import bpy

new_uvmap_name = 'UVCombined'

for mesh in bpy.data.meshes:
    if new_uvmap_name not in mesh.uv_layers:
        new_uv_map = mesh.uv_layers.new(name=new_uvmap_name)
        new_uv_map.active = True
```